# Why would the changeling take Garak to Sisko?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion, changeling

Before the opening credits of *In Purgatory's Shadow*:

> [In Runabout]
>
> (Bashir is waiting for him with a phaser.)
>
> BASHIR: Going somewhere?
>
> GARAK: I really must remember to stop underestimating you, Doctor. How did you  know?
>
> BASHIR: You mean that you were lying about the contents of the message? You said you'd given up on the Cardassian survivors who were lost in the Gamma  Quadrant. Well, Ziyal was right. You're not the giving up sort.
>
> GARAK: Very good, Doctor. You've come a long way from the naive young man I met five years ago. You've become distrustful and suspicious. It suits you.
>
> [...]
>
> GARAK: Yes, but aside from that, we were very close. He was my mentor, and I'm not going to turn my back on him. If it'll make you feel better, you can come with me. All you have to do is come up with an excuse why you need the runabout and we could leave immediately.
>
> BASHIR: So let me get this straight. You want me to lie to my commanding officer, violate Starfleet regulations, and go with you on a mission into the Gamma Quadrant which will probably get us both killed?
>
> GARAK: I'm ready when you are.
>
> BASHIR: In that case, let's go. To Captain's Sisko's office.

Later in the episode we find out Bashir has been replaced by a changeling.

**Why would the changeling (as Bashir) take Garak to Captain Sisko?**

Comment: Why wouldn't he?

Comment: Letting Garak go alone seems safer. Telling Sisko risks the Federation finding out about the fleet which is preparing to retake Cardassia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The changeling was maintaining his cover.

It doesn't matter if the Federation learns about the Dominion fleet hiding in the nebula, because the Federation has listening posts that will tell them of a fleet approaching the wormhole anyway. All that changes is the timing; once discovered, the Dominion fleet immediately heads for the wormhole. The important part of the plan is that the Dominion bypasses DS9. Because they immediately announce their alliance with Cardassia, everyone assumes that they're simply grouping up the two fleets for a combined attack on the station. The obvious counter move is to gather the Federation and Klingon fleets, which is what the Dominion actually wants.

I also doubt that the changeling was killed in the explosion. His bomb was obviously on a timer, so he had plenty of time to beam out whether he was caught or not.